# Are bumps by community user shown/logged somewhere?

Tags: support, bumping, community-user

[Community user](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) bumps some old unanswered question from time to time. Is this activity shown somewhere?

Quite often it can happen that someone edits a post in order to improve it - since the questions had been bumped anyway. I did this recently at meta, when I check the [timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5048/timeline) of that question, no activity by community user is shown there, my revision is shown the last activity. So, based on the timeline, it looks like I was the one to bump the question.

Is there a possibility how to find out that the question had indeed already been bumped by Community user?

Comment: I found a related question at meta.SO:
[Is there any way to see which posts Community has bumped?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110177/is-there-any-way-to-see-which-posts-community-has-bumped). But no answers are given there.

Comment: According to the 2016 answer in the above link, the Revision/Edit History now shows the community-user bumps. I'd like to know its bumping criteria, though.

Comment: @ryang I believe the criteria describing how the bumped questions are chosen are described here: [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578#48579)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Even [community’s activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) does not load on mobile. Right?

Comment: @TymaGaidash If you mean this problem, I can observe it on desktop - I do not think it is specific to mobile: ["Activity" tab for the Community user's network profile sometimes leads to a server error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280897).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, bumps by Community User are now recorded in the   [timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info) and the [revision history](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/edit-history/info). They are also recorded in the [Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) as `PostHistoryTypeid=50`.

- Shog9's answer here: [Is there any way to see which posts Community has bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110177#279201)
- May 2016 entry here: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445)
- The part about PostHistory table in the [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677).

Comment: I have added this answer so that this long-forgotten question doesn't remain unanswered. The answer is CW - feel free to add further information, if there is something else worth including.